# Azure B2C Custom Policy Authorize endpoint giving 404

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

In custom policy if I wanted to change Authorize & METADATA endpoint from login.microsoftonline.com to tenant.b2clogin.com

What should we use.

I get 404 for the endpoint

Comment: You could try this work around. Hope you would get the outline. If you have any more query feel free to ask. Thanks

Comment: I believe this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63123070/5022951. At least, it answered the same question for me. Apologies if yours is a different problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Your Case**

I wanted to change Authorize & METADATA endpoint from login.microsoftonline.com to tenant.b2clogin.com

**Solution**

In your case you need to configure custom URI for your application. To do that please have a look on the following steps

**Step to follow**

When you set up an identity provider for sign-up and sign-in in your Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) [B2C application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview), you need to specify a redirect URL.

> In the past, login.microsoftonline.com was used, now you should be
>   using b2clogin.com.

```
For Example https://YourTenantName.b2clogin.com
```

**Following settings that might need to change when using b2clogin.com**

> 1. Set the redirect URLs in your identity provider applications to use
>      b2clogin.com.
> 2. Set your Azure AD B2C application to use b2clogin.com for user flow
>      references and token endpoints.
> 3. If you are using MSAL, you need to set the ValidateAuthority
>      property to false.
> 4. Make sure that you change any Allowed Origins that you have defined
>      in the CORS settings for [user-interface customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom-dynamic).

Go to ***user policy*** of your b2c app. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Click on ***page layout*** like below:

[image]

***Run your custom flow***. Take a look below

[image]

> **Note:**
>
> You can use both the tenant name and the tenant GUID as follows:
>
> 1. https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com
>      (which still refers to onmicrosoft.com)
> 2. https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-guid (in which
>      case there is no reference to Microsoft at all)
>
> **Remember**
>
> You cannot use a custom domain for your Azure Active Directory B2C tenant, e.g.
>
> https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-custom-domain-name would
>   not work.

If you feel any problem during implementation you could refer official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin)

For your more queries you can also refer [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/8057)

Hoping this will help to figure out the way around. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OPs question because he is asking about to do this with custom policies