# In Azure B2C Custom Policies, do I need to migrate Sign-In Metadata URLs to b2clogin.com?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin) states that microsoftonline.com is being deprecated in Azure AD B2C *redirect* URLs.

I have an Azure B2C Custom Policy that uses a Technical Policy, LoginUser, for an OpenIdConnect sign-in.  It contains Metadata keys as follows:

```
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
```

All the examples I can find online do exactly the same thing.

**My question**

Do I need to migrate these to b2clogin.com URLs, or will these remain functional after December 4th 2020?  To be clear, these aren't redirect URLs - these are internal to a Technical Profile in a Custom Policy.  (I'm hoping the answer's 'no', as changing them following the suggestions in the linked article doesn't work for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these do not need to be modified at all. These endpoints are for communication to an underlying Azure AD, and Azure AD is not deprecating their endpoint.

The linked article has no directions to make the changes you’re suggesting either.

The linked article is complete, follow it exactly.

Comment: Thanks @Jas, that's clear then.  (I also received a helpful reply from Microsoft on this and they say they are working on changes to help disambiguate the documentation.)